# Two applications having the same name - just changing one .C file name?

Tags: c++, terminal, command

I have a fairly easy question I guess, but I am not sure how to search for the answer. If I have two applications with the same name, meaning especially the `.C file` that includes the `main-method`, can I just change the name of one of these `.C files` and run the application by this new name or will I have to change more somewhere else?

Additionally I want to know if commands for applications generally are simply the `.C file` name of the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify the name of the application using your compiler/linker.

GCC example:

```
g++ somefile.c -o application.exe
```

MSVC example:

```
cl /c somefile.c
link /out:application.exe somefile.obj
```

If you omit the name then by default GCC will produce a file named `a.out`, and MSVC will use the name of the first `.obj` file supplied to it, with a `.exe` extension.

If you are using an IDE, then you will be able to find equivalent settings to change the output name, and the defaults will probably be different (in Visual Studio for example, the default output name is the name of your project).

Comment: Two questions about this: 1. In Terminal if i go to the project folder and type `g++ somefile.c -o application.exe` the execute command for `somefile.c` will become `application`? 2. Where is this statement/information saved within the file system?

Comment: @Streight Which operating system are you using?

Comment: @Streight In that case you would need to type the full name of the output to execute it. If that name included an extension (such as `.exe` from my example) you would type `application.exe` (although you probably wouldn't use that extension in Linux). In Linux any file can be executable, and this is done by setting the executable bit using `chmod`. If you type the name of your file in a terminal, and the executable bit is set, then the OS knows to execute it. Note that this is done for you automatically when you compile to an executable.

Comment: The executable bit is stored (along with other file attributes) in an inode in the file system.